# How to use data from another table in my view?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, development

I'm struggling to learn Joomla 3.x and am baffled as to how to join my record to another table and use the joined data in my view/form. I'm familiar with components that use something similar to this:
(I've only included partial snippets because the approach I'm familiar with seems quite common throughout other components and my google results)

**models/mymodel.php**

```
// JOIN and retrieve the data I'm interested in:
function getData()
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('a.name, b.lastvisitDate FROM #__mytable AS a')
          ->innerJoin('#__users AS b ON a.created_by = b.id');
```

**views\myview\tmpl\default.php**

```
// The data from the joined data is available for display something like this
echo "<span>" . $this->item->lastvisitDate. "</span>"
```

Now, with Joomla 3, I see a series of function such as `prepareTable`,`getTable`,`getForm`,`loadFormData`, and `getItem`.

As best as I can tell, it's using predefined forms/XML, fields and such that describe the primary table in great detail.  I'm able to *change* data in `getItem` that shows on the view, but am clueless about how to get usable data from the second table!

What's the best-practice way to join my primary table to another, and be able to display that information with the view.  (*e.g. JOIN myTable.created_by on #__users.id to get something like last visit date.)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best-practice way of doing it (please comment if there's a better way), or it is exactly what you're looking for, but here's my approach using a Joomla article as an example:

*Files of Interest*

- components\com_content\views\article\view.html.php
- components\com_content\models\article.php

**Modify view.html.php**

Near the top of `public function display($tpl = null)`, you'll see a line like this:

`$this->item = $this->get('Item');`

It gets the article data from function `getItem` located in `models\article.php`

Duplicate that line to something like this:

`$this->item        = $this->get('Mydata');`

**Modify article.php**

Now you have to add the function to get the data you're interested in with this block of code: (named according to how you're calling it, preceded by 'get')

```
 public function getMydata($pk = null)
{
    $myItemObj = new stdClass();
    $myItemObj->something = 'something you need';

    $db    = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('*')
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__users'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = 467');
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $myItemObj->MydbObj = $db->loadObject();

    return $myItemObj;
}
```

In your view, you can now access that data like this:

```
echo "<span>". $this->myData->something ."</span>";
echo "<span>". $this->myData->MydbObj->username ."</span>";
```

You may want to check [Using multiple models in an MVC component](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_multiple_models_in_an_MVC_component) if you need a more comprehensive solution.